# Is there ever a case for 'new' when using dependency injection?

Tags: java, oop, spring, dependency-injection, guice

Does dependency injection mean that you don't ever need the 'new' keyword? Or is it reasonable to directly create simple leaf classes such as collections?

In the example below I inject the comparator, query and dao, but the SortedSet is directly instantiated:

```
public Iterable<Employee> getRecentHires()
{
    SortedSet<Employee> entries = new TreeSet<Employee>(comparator);
    entries.addAll(employeeDao.findAll(query));
    return entries;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just because Dependency Injection is a useful pattern doesn't mean that we use it for everything.  Even when using DI, there will often be a need for *new*.  Don't delete new just yet.

Answer (score 7):

One way I typically decide whether or not to use dependency injection is whether or not I need to mock or stub out the collaborating class when writing a unit test for the class under test.  For instance, in your example you (correctly) are injecting the DAO because if you write a unit test for your class, you probably don't want any data to actually be written to the database.  Or perhaps a collaborating class writes files to the filesystem or is dependent on an external resource.  Or the behavior is unpredictable or difficult to account for in a unit test.  In those cases it's best to inject those dependencies.

For collaborating classes like TreeSet, I normally would not inject those because there is usually no need to mock out simple classes like these.

One final note: when a field cannot be injected for whatever reason, but I still would like to mock it out in a test, I have found the [Junit-addons PrivateAccessor](http://junit-addons.sourceforge.net/junitx/util/PrivateAccessor.html) class helpful to be able to switch the class's private field to a mock object created by [EasyMock](http://www.easymock.org/) (or jMock or whatever other mocking framework you prefer).

Comment: Spring also has the `ReflectionTestUtils` class for operations on private members.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with using *new* like how it's shown in your code snippet.

Consider the case of wanting to append String snippets. Why would you want to ask the injector for a StringBuilder ?

In another situation that I've faced, I needed to have a thread running in accordance to the lifecycle of my container. In that case, I had to do a *new Thread()* because my Injector was created after the callback method for container startup was called. And once the injector was ready, I hand injected some managed classes into my Thread subclass.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course.

Dependency injection is meant for situations where there could be several possible  instantiation targets of which the client may not be aware (or capable of making a choice) of compile time.

However, there are enough situations where you do know exactly what you want to instantiate, so there is no need for DI.

This is just like invoking functions in object-oriented langauges: just because you can use dynamic binding, doesn't mean that you can't use good old static dispatching (e.g., when you split your method into several private operations).

Answer (score 0):

My thinking is that DI is awesome and great to wire layers and also pieces of your code that needs sto be flexible to potential change. Sure we can say everything can potentially need changing, but we all know in practice some stuff just wont be touched.

So when DI is overkill I use 'new' and just let it roll.

Ex: for me wiring a Model to the View to the Controller layer.. it's always done via DI. Any Algorithms my apps uses, DI and also any pluggable reflective code, DI. Database layer.. DI but pretty much any other object being used in my system is handled with a common 'new'.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that in today, framework-driven environment you instantiate objects less and less. For example, Servlets are instantiated by servlet container, beans in Spring instantiated with Spring etc.

Still, when using persistence layer, you will instantiate your persisted objects before they have been persisted. When using Hibernate, for example you will call new on your persisted object before calling save on your HibernateTemplate.